# Float items below ExpandableListview

Tags: android

[Before expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePIKO.png)

[After expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbVrm.png)

[İf height match_parent override other views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Znf.png)

[I WANT TO GET LİKE THİS EXPAND AND CLOSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8oaT.jpg)

[I WANT TO GET LİKE THİS EXPAND AND CLOSE OTHER EXPANDABLE LİST VİEWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BftA.jpg)

It is my xml file for showing expandable list etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sizeozel_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:text="SİZE ÖZEL"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/size_ozel_divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/exp_referans_linkim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></ExpandableListView>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/size_ozel_divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/exp_satislarim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></ExpandableListView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/size_ozel_divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="235dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
        android:text="İş Ortaklarım"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/size_ozel_divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:text="Sepetim"
        />


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/size_ozel_divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
        android:text="Alınan Ürünler"
        />


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/size_ozel_divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/exp_bilgilerim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="355dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></ExpandableListView>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/size_ozel_divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My adapter java file for expandable list view

```
package arabulkazan.albatros.com.arabulkazan.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


import arabulkazan.albatros.com.arabulkazan.MainActivity;
import arabulkazan.albatros.com.arabulkazan.R;

import static arabulkazan.albatros.com.arabulkazan.Fragments.SizeOzel.ref_childListMap;
import static arabulkazan.albatros.com.arabulkazan.Fragments.SizeOzel.ref_groupList;

public class Exp_Ref_List_Adapter implements ExpandableListAdapter {
    Context context;


    public Exp_Ref_List_Adapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return ref_groupList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupIndex) {
        String group = ref_groupList.get(groupIndex);
        List<String> childInfoList = ref_childListMap.get(group);
        return childInfoList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupIndex) {
        return ref_groupList.get(groupIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupIndex, int childIndex) {
        String group = ref_groupList.get(groupIndex);
        List<String> childInfoList = ref_childListMap.get(group);
        return childInfoList.get(childIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupIndex) {
        return groupIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupIndex, int childIndex) {
        return childIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    // This method will return a View object displayed in group list item.
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupIndex, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // Create the group view object.
        LinearLayout groupLayoutView = new LinearLayout(context);
        groupLayoutView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);





        // Create and add a textview in returned group view.
        String groupText = ref_groupList.get(groupIndex);
        TextView groupTextView = new TextView(context);
        groupTextView.setText(groupText);
        groupTextView.setTextSize(30);
        groupLayoutView.addView(groupTextView);

        return groupLayoutView;
    }

    // This method will return a View object displayed in child list item.
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupIndex, int childIndex, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // First get child text/
        Object childObj = this.getChild(groupIndex, childIndex);
        String childText = (String)childObj;

        // Create a TextView to display child text.
        TextView childTextView = new TextView(context);
        childTextView.setText(childText);
        childTextView.setTextSize(20);
       // childTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);



        // Set child textview offset left. Then it will align to the right of the group image.
        childTextView.setPadding(15,0,0,0);

        return childTextView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupIndex, int childIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupIndex) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupIndex) {


    }

    @Override
    public long getCombinedChildId(long groupIndex, long childIndex) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getCombinedGroupId(long groupIndex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And my main fragment java code

```
public class Main extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
public static List<String> ref_groupList = null;
    public  static Map<String, List<String>> ref_childListMap = null;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_page, container, false);

this.referans_linkim("Referans Linkim","12345678","kobi45678");

Exp_Ref_List_Adapter exp_ref_list_adapter=new Exp_Ref_List_Adapter(SizeOzel.this.getActivity());

        final ExpandableListView exp_ref = (ExpandableListView)root.findViewById(R.id.exp_referans_linkim);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();//for determine indicator position
       SizeOzel.this.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;

        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int elli=    (int) (50 * scale + 0.5f);
    int on= (int) (10 * scale + 0.5f);

        exp_ref.setIndicatorBounds(width-elli,width-on);

        exp_ref.setAdapter(exp_ref_list_adapter);

// Add on group expand listener.
        exp_ref.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupIndex) {
                // Get total group size.
                int groupListSize = ref_groupList.size();

                // Close other expanded group.
                for(int i=0;i < groupListSize; i++) {
                    if(i!=groupIndex) {
                        exp_ref.collapseGroup(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

 // Referansım linkim data assign
    private void referans_linkim(String name,String temsil_kod,String kobi_kod)
    {
        if(this.ref_groupList == null)
        {
            this.ref_groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        if(this.ref_childListMap == null)
        {
            this.ref_childListMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        }

        if(!this.ref_groupList.contains(name)) {
            this.ref_groupList.add(name);
        }

        // Create child list.
        List<String> childList = new ArrayList<String>();
        childList.add("Temsilci Kodu:  " + temsil_kod);
        childList.add("Kobi Kodu:  " + kobi_kod);

        // Add child data list in the map, key is group name.
        this.ref_childListMap.put(name, childList);
    }

}
```

When i try to expand my expandable listview its expanded.But it compress itself to determine width and height.I want to float items that under expandable list.How can i do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove fix height is only option

Comment: What do you mean? So for my expandable list view      android:layout_height="49dp" to wrap_content? I tried that but then it takes up extra space without expanded.For ex. takes up extra space for 1 child without expanded and writes dynamic child data under items

Comment: try to put match_parent

Comment: I have edited my question. You can see what is happening if I try that "İf height match_parent override other views" i encounter with this.

Comment: I have copied your layout and tried it but i want to asked you that why you take multiple ExpandableVIew instead of single ExpandableView

Comment: I have updated 2 new images upon your request.Last 2 one that I want to get.  I hope you understand me.Two diffirent list views because diffirent datas on them.Thats why i have created multiple ExpandableVIew

Comment: but you can add different data in single expandableview buddy

Comment: Ty for help . I've changed all expandableviews to linearlayouts.In it some text and image like before.I have checked  visible or gone  in java then my problem is gone.

Comment: that is not a right solution but its ok